# mod_rewrite help

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

For some unknown reason, my rewrite rule does not fire. Can you advise ?

- `/extranet/.htaccess` (1)
- `/extranet/stable/`
- `/extranet/dev/`
- `/extranet/dev/.htaccess` (2)

The first .htaccess redirects all traffic to the *stable* folder, except for URLs specifically pointed at the *dev* folder. That works fine.

Inside the *dev* folder, the second .htaccess is supposed to rewrite `/extranet/dev/foo/` to `/extranet/dev/index.php?app=foo`.

And that fails me.

```
IndexIgnore *
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
#--------------------------------------------
# FRIENDLY URLs
#--------------------------------------------

# if the following conditions are met, SKIP the rewriteRules.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(|_css/|_js/|_img/) [NC]
RewriteRule . - [L]


RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?app=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first alternation option of `^/(|_css/|_js/|_img/)` is `^/` and that tested against `REQUEST_URI` is always true.

Comment: even if i remove the whole rewriteCond , only leaving the last rewriteRule directive, the rewrite does not fire up.